# relocated truncation to fit: 16 against `.text'

Tags: assembly, ld, x86-16, bootloader, gnu-assembler

I hope you guys are having a great day. I have a question about compiling assembly into a `.bin`. I am trying to use [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939593/mingws-ld-cannot-perform-pe-operations-on-non-pe-output-file) to fix it, but even then I get `relocated truncation to fit: 16 against '.text'.

**bootReal.s**:

```
#generate 16-bit code
.code16

#hint the assembler that here is the executable code located
.text
.globl _start;
#boot code entry
_start:
      jmp _boot                           #jump to boot code
      welcome: .asciz "Hello, World\n\r"  #here we define the string

     .macro mWriteString str              #macro which calls a function to print a string
          leaw  \str, %si
          call .writeStringIn
     .endm

     #function to print the string
     .writeStringIn:
          lodsb
          orb  %al, %al
          jz   .writeStringOut
          movb $0x0e, %ah
          int  $0x10
          jmp  .writeStringIn
     .writeStringOut:
     ret

_boot:
     mWriteString welcome

     #move to 510th byte from the start and append boot signature
     . = _start + 510
     .byte 0x55
     .byte 0xaa
```

Commands I used:

`as bootReal.s -o bootReal.s`

`ld.exe -o file.tmp bootReal.o` <- this one throws the error

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `ld -Ttext=0` or `-Ttext=0x7c00` whichever you choose. Make sure you set up `ds` to match though.

Comment: @Jester `ld -Ttext=0x7c00` alsoo throws an error where `-0x7c00` "is not a file or directory"

Comment: You typed something wrong. Extra space somewhere maybe? Alternatively try with `--image-base=0`.

Comment: @Jester : That would have been my guess... I assume they wrote `-Ttext= 0x7c00` instead of `-Ttext=0x7c00`

Comment: Please post the complete error message including the indicated address or line number!

Comment: @fuz the error is in the title. It is a relocation error. Almost certainly it would have been because of `leaw  \str, %si` if the default linker script used by LD on Windows defaulted to a VMA (org) >=0x10000 (which is almost certainly the case)

Comment: I also assume `as bootReal.s -o bootReal.s` was meant to be `as bootReal.s -o bootReal.o`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @jester suggested you will want to set a Virtual Memory Address(VMA) starting point. The linker you are using on Windows has used an internal linker script that sets a VMA >= 0x10000. So any references to absolute addresses that can't fit in 16-bits will generate a relocation error. You can't fit an address >= 0x10000 into a 16-bit register so the linker aborts with an error similar to:

> (.text+0x1f): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.text'

The error may be slightly different if you are using a 64-bit tool chain but it will be something like `R_???????_16 against '.text'`

To fix this you can either create your own linker script or set the base VMA to the appropriate value on the LD command line. I would recommend using `-Ttext=0x7c00` and setting DS to 0x0000 in your bootloader.

I have [General Bootloader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32705076/3857942) tips that discuss many of the problems writing a bootloader. You shouldn't assume that when your bootloader is running that the segment registers have any particular value. If you use `-Ttext=0x7c00` as a VMA (ORG) then you need to set DS to zero. The [segment:offset](https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html) pair 0x0000:0x7c00 = physical address 0x07c00 (0x0000<<4+0x7c00). 0x07c00 is where the legacy BIOS will load your boot sector into memory.

If you ever get a relocation error like:

> (.text+0x1f): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.text'

You can always use OBJDUMP to show the relocation entries in the object file. In this case since you are writing 16-bit code you'll want to have OBJDUMP dump the code (`-D`); decode as 16-bit instructions (`-Mi8086`) and output the relocation entries (`-r`). The output of `objdump -Mi8086 -Dr bootReal.o` would appear similar to this (it may vary based on the linker being used):

> ```
> 00000000 <_start>:
>    0:   eb 1b                   jmp    1d <_boot>
>
> 00000002 <welcome>:
>    2:   48                      dec    %ax
>    3:   65                      gs
>    4:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%di)
>    5:   6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%di)
>    6:   6f                      outsw  %ds:(%si),(%dx)
>    7:   2c 20                   sub    $0x20,%al
>    9:   57                      push   %di
>    a:   6f                      outsw  %ds:(%si),(%dx)
>    b:   72 6c                   jb     79 <_boot+0x5c>
>    d:   64 0a 0d                or     %fs:(%di),%cl
>         ...
>
> 00000011 <.writeStringIn>:
>   11:   ac                      lods   %ds:(%si),%al
>   12:   08 c0                   or     %al,%al
>   14:   74 06                   je     1c <.writeStringOut>
>   16:   b4 0e                   mov    $0xe,%ah
>   18:   cd 10                   int    $0x10
>   1a:   eb f5                   jmp    11 <.writeStringIn>
>
> 0000001c <.writeStringOut>:
>   1c:   c3                      ret
>
> 0000001d <_boot>:
>   1d:   8d 36 02 00             lea    0x2,%si
>                         1f: R_386_16    .text
>   21:   e8 ed ff                call   11 <.writeStringIn>
>         ...
>  1fc:   00 00                   add    %al,(%bx,%si)
>  1fe:   55                      push   %bp
>  1ff:   aa                      stos   %al,%es:(%di)
> ```

In the relocation error `.text+0x1f` was referenced as the source of the problem. If you look in the OBJDUMP output there is a relocation entry:

> ```
>   1d:   8d 36 02 00             lea    0x2,%si
>                         1f: R_386_16    .text
> ```

This relocation is associated with the instruction above it. Which means essentially that the linker tried to generate an offset for the `LEA` instruction but the value couldn't be represented in a 16-bit value. *SI* is 16-bit register and can't have a value placed in it >= 0x10000.

---

### Problems with the Code

- You want to properly set DS to 0 if using a VMA (ORG) of 0x7c00
- Ensure string instructions like `lodsb` move through strings in the forward direction. Use the `CLD` instruction to clear the Direction Flag (DF=0).
- It is usually a good idea to set your own stack pointer *SS:SP*. This is important if you ever read more data off the disk into memory. You don't know where the BIOS set *SS:SP* and you don't want to clobber it. A convenient place to set the the stack is just below the bootloader at 0x0000:0x7c00.
- To prevent your bootloader from running semi random code after the last instruction you will want to put the processor in some kind of infinite loop. An easy way would be `jmp .`
- LD will generate an executable file in a format that is not a binary file and can't be run as a bootloader. You can have the linker write a binary file with the `--oformat=binary` option.

The revised code could look like:

```
#generate 16-bit code
.code16

#hint the assembler that here is the executable code located
.text
.globl _start;
#boot code entry
_start:
      jmp _boot                           #jump to boot code
      welcome: .asciz "Hello, World\n\r"  #here we define the string

     .macro mWriteString str              #macro which calls a function to print a string
          leaw  \str, %si
          call .writeStringIn
     .endm

     #function to print the string
     .writeStringIn:
          lodsb
          orb  %al, %al
          jz   .writeStringOut
          movb $0x0e, %ah
          int  $0x10
          jmp  .writeStringIn
     .writeStringOut:
     ret

_boot:
     xor %ax, %ax
     mov %ax, %ds      # Initialize the DS segment to zero
     mov %ax, %ss      # Set the stack pointer below bootloader at 0x0000:0x7c00
     mov $0x7c00, %sp
     cld               # Clear Direction Flag (DF=0) to set forward movement on string
                       # instructions

     mWriteString welcome
     jmp .             # Enter an infinite loop to stop executing code beyond this point

     #move to 510th byte from the start and append boot signature
     . = _start + 510
     .byte 0x55
     .byte 0xaa
```

To assemble and run you could use something like:

```
as bootReal.s -o bootReal.o
ld -Ttext=0x7c00 --oformat=binary -o boot.bin bootReal.o
```

An alternative is to generate an executable with LD and use OBJCOPY to convert the executable to a binary file:

```
as bootReal.s -o bootReal.o
ld -Ttext=0x7c00 -o file.tmp bootReal.o
objcopy -O binary file.tmp boot.bin
```

Either way should generate a 512 byte binary file (bootloader) called `boot.bin`. If you ran it with QEMU with `qemu-system-i386 -fda boot.bin` the output would look similar to:

[image]